# Error al ejecutar script de python

Tags: python

Estoy tratando de ejecutar este script de esta forma:`sudo /etc/openhab2/scripts/hola.py , pero tengo el siguiente error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/etc/openhab2/scripts/hola.py", line 4, in <module>
    import telebot # Importamos las librería
ImportError: No module named telebot
```

Cuando lo ejecuto con `python /etc/openhab2/scripts/hola.py` trabaja bien.

Ya lo hice ejecutable con `chmod +x hola.py` pero no logro ejecutarlo sin especificar python al inicio.

Adjunto el script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
print "Hola que mas????"
import telebot # Importamos las librería
import os # Importamos la libreria para enviar mensajes al sistema
from subprocess import call

TOKEN = '768259143:AAF5nyuHZ8vqdkzjgjwHeerYYeSiekMGSB4' # Ponemos nuestro Token generado con el @BotFather

bot = telebot.TeleBot(TOKEN) # Combinamos la declaración del Token con la función de la API,definimos el token.



@bot.message_handler(commands=['menu']) # Este manejador lo que hace es filtrar lo que se escribe en el bot, en este caso solo se ejecuta si se escribe "menu" en el bot
def send_menu(message): # Definimos una funcion llamda "send_menu" con el parametro message
    if message.chat.type == "private": # Define si el usuario esta en un chat privado o grupal ( hay que estudiar esto)
        keyboard = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardMarkup() # esto es como una orden para desplegar un una especia de marco
        keyboard.row( # Este comando indica que todo se desplegue en la misma fila
                    telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton('\xF0\x9F\x92\xA1 Luz Comedor on', callback_data='switch/comedor/on -m play-34ea346ff7ac') # Muestra un boton co$
                    )
        keyboard.row( # Este comando indica que todo se desplegue en la misma fila

                    telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton('\xF0\x9F\x92\xA1 Luz Comedor Off', callback_data='switch/comedor/off -m play-34ea346ff7ac'), # Muestra un boton$

                    telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton('\xF0\x9F\x93\xBA Television', callback_data='televisor/boton/on -m play-34ea346ff7ac') # Muestra un boton Con e$
                    )
        bot.send_message(784245717,"Main Menu...",reply_markup=keyboard) # Envia un mensaje con el texto "Main Menu" y todo el el Markup

#callback del keyboard de markup
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def iq_callback(query):
    # Sends Telegram received command through MQTT to OH2
    os.system("mosquitto_pub -u openhabian -P 7121799422 -t broadlink/" + query.data)


@bot.message_handler(commands=['canales']) # Este manejador lo que hace es filtrar lo que se escribe en el bot, en este caso solo se ejecuta si se escribe "menu" en el$
def send_menu(message): # Definimos una funcion llamda "send_menu" con el parametro message
    if message.chat.type == "private": # Define si el usuario esta en un chat privado o grupal ( hay que estudiar esto)
        keyboard = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardMarkup() # esto es como una orden para desplegar un una especia de marco
        keyboard.row( # Este comando indica que todo se desplegue en la misma fila
                    telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton('\xF0\x9F\x92\xA1 Canales' , callback_data='deco/boton/2 -m play-34ea346ff7ac') # Muestra un boton co
                    )
        bot.send_message(784245717,"Main Menu...",reply_markup=keyboard) # Envia un mensaje con el texto "Main Menu" y todo el el Markup


#callback del keyboard de markup
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def iq_callback(query):
    # Sends Telegram received command through MQTT to OH2

      print(os.popen('mosquitto_pub -u openhabian -P 7121799422 -t broadlink/' + query.data).readline())
      x = _
      print(x)

bot.polling(True) # Inicia el Script
```

Muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿Qué te da `which python` cuando lo ejecutas como usuario normal y cuando eres root?

Comment: Hola abulafia , el resultado es igual como usuario normal que como root: `usr/bin/python`.

Comment: ¿Y si pones `echo $PYTHONPATH`? ¿Cómo has instalado telebot?

Comment: Esta es la versionde python, `python -V`  `Python 2.7.13`   Cuando pongo  `echo $PYTHONPATH ` no muestra nada, he instalado asi:`$ pip install pyTelegramBotAPI`. Gracias por tu ayuda.

Comment: Cuando busco telebot encuentro esto: `$ sudo find / -name telebot`
`$ /home/openhabian/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/telebot` Gracias.

Comment: Al parecer es algo relacionado con el sys.path, haré algunas pruebas y les contaré.

Answer (score 0):

No es la mejor solución, pero...
prueba instalar el modulo para el superusuario (llamas a su entorno al elevar los permisos con sudo).
#sudo pip3 install pyTelegramBotAPI
o
#sudo pip install pyTelegramBotAPI

suerte y nos comentas....